# premature End-of-file (EOF) error when reading JSON data in R

Tags: json, r, api, mailchimp

I am extracting JSON data from an application (MailChimp) using the vendor's API and using the following code (where "path1" is my API call):

input                  <- fromJSON(path1)

I get the following error:

***Error in finalize_push_parser(bigint_as_char) : 
  parse error: premature EOF***

When I paste the API call directly into Chrome's RESTful API client and send the request it tells me the request didn't return any data (presumably it's hitting the same error and crashing and failing to give the return data).

My understanding is that this is telling me there is something wrong in the source data inside the APP (e.g. unclosed bracket, carriage return inside a field, etc.) that is causing R to break when asked to read/process it.

I can get return data if I limit my request to only 100, 500, 1000...4500 records...but when I ask for 5000 records I get the empty return set...so my offending record must be somewhere between row 4501 and 5000...

I can see two ways forward:

1) add something to my R code to tell it to bypass/skip the offending record and process everything else (it is acceptable if a few bad records are omitted from the return set)

2) write a routine to help me isolate and "see" the offending record so I can go into the front-end of the app and look up and remove that record from the system (so it doesn't cause problems for API calls on the back-end)

I am looking for assistance with the commands/code/syntax to address either path - either how to skip a "bad" record or how to see the bad record (in this case "email address") that is causing the problem...

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting `fromJSON()` from?  Which package?

Comment: I recommend using a proper http client like `httr`, then parse the result with `jsonlite`

Comment: actually I think issue was with the application and its API.  My calls that were good when I limited response to 4K rows but failed at 5K rows weren't tripping on a bad record...they were hitting some kind of internal processing constraint on the application/API side.  I am now submitting my calls with low limits (e.g. 1K per call) and looping over the call many times to pull all the data I need.